# Using std::initializer_list over the DLL boundary

Tags: c++, stl, initializer-list

It's well known fact that exposing the STL containers over the boundary is very bad idea due to the compiler compatibility issues, move semantics, etc... Therefore the array-like data is passed with pointers (begin and size, or begin and end) or with the custom object.

Logically, it seems that exposing constructors with `std:initializer_list<> const&` over the boundary is a bad idea too. Is this correct? Also, is there a way to ensure similar experience that `std:initializer_list` provides, but in the safe manner? For example, having custom `Vector` object, which encapsulates `std::vector<int>` but can be constructed using `Vector({1,2,3,4,5})` from other client assemblies.

Comment: `std:initializer_list` is no container (your assumption is wrong)

Comment: @DieterLücking - I didn't totally get your comment, sorry. Which assumption? Can you please expand?